# How to quickly render a custom asset browser prop preview

Tags: rendering, workflow, asset-browser, workbench-render-engine

I currently have a few dozen models that I'm organizing into an asset browser catalogues. The default preview icon for each asset is rendered from a fixed angle in a workbench renderer, but I would prefer a more telling render for each asset.

So I'm thinking how to do this in the most efficient way and this is what I have come up with:

1. Create a scene in each blend file that has my assets, add some basic lightning, transparency and a camera.
2. Import an asset from the asset library.
3. Adjust camera position.
4. Render, save image on disk.
5. Open up asset properties, load the custom preview image from disk

Can this process be simplified or sped up in any way?